# ZF2 subdomain routing with variable point's in subdomain

Tags: routes, subdomain, zend-framework2

I need to setup a route for my ZF2 application with a variable point in it.

e.g., I need to route subdomains like;

```
john.van.der.berg.domain.tld
nick.van.eisselsain.domain.tld
james.morris.domain.tld
```

I know the point's in the subdomain will always 1, 2 or 3

I now have to follow setup for my route but I can't figure out how
to do it with the points?

```
 'username' => array(
                'type'    => 'hostname',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => ':username.domain.localhost',
                    'constraints' => array(
                            'action'  => 'username',
                            'username' => '[a-zA-Z0-9.]{1,3}*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Users\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Users',
                        'action'        => 'website',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The dot in the `regex` needs to be escaped `\.` since `.` is ANY character. Furthermore, i don't know this exactly, but i assume that every `.` on a domain would be a new sub domain. So you'd have a sub-sub-subdomain ultimately, which is not to be able to get configured like that. Suggestion: `trim` the username for `alphanumeric`-chars only. This makes your routing easy, too.

Comment: After re-reading your comment. You are right. It's not possible to do this in one route config. I need to create 3 configs for possibilities and handle this by a plugin or something to set the right route name for redirections.

Answer (score 0):

As of ZF 2.1.3, the code you showed should work properly.